# angular2: Access property of pipe returning object

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a custom angular2 pipe, which converts uid's (strings) to `UserInfo` objects using a service.

```
@Pipe({name: 'userInfo'})
export class UserInfoPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(public _userService: UserService) {
    }

    transform(uid:string) : any {
        /*let users = this._userService.users.filter((u)=> {
            return u.uid==uid;
        });
        if(users.length==1) return users[0];
        return null;*/

        return {"Name":"hans","Age":13};
    }
}
```

And in my component I have a binding:

```
 <Label row="4"  text="Author: {{event?.author | userInfo | .Name}}" class="small-spacing"></Label>
```

`event?.author` returns the UID, and after piping it through `userInfo` I have an object. But how can I access properties of that object? Is there a syntax for that? `.Name` doesn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just found out that

```
(event?.author | userInfo).Name
```

does exactly what I want: It displays the `Name` property of the object returned by the pipe.

Comment: That is wicked. Did not know about that syntax. Super useful!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the correct way, but I'd pass additional parameter into your pipe.

```
<Label row="4"  text="Author: {{event?.author | userInfo : {"field": "Name"} }}" class="small-spacing"></Label>
```

In the pipe I check this parameter and do some special logic:

```
@Pipe({name: 'userInfo'})
export class UserInfoPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public _userService: UserService) {
  }

  transform(uid:string, params) : any {
    if (params.field && params.field == 'Name') {

        /*let users = this._userService.users.filter((u)=> {
            return u.uid==uid;
        });
        if(users.length==1) return users[0];
        return null;*/

        return {"Name":"hans","Age":13};
    }
  }
}
```